# C++ Convert Sytem::String^ to LPCOLESTR

Tags: string, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, converters

I write in mixed mode (C++/CLI) and I can not resolve this problem:

```
String ^progID = "Matrikon.OPC.Server";
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT result = CLSIDFromProgID(progID, &clsid);
```

error C2664: 'CLSIDFromProgID' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'LPCOLESTR'

How can I convert `String^` to `LPCOLESTR` ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets convert System::String to char*

`IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(progID);
char *pNewCharStr = static_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());`

second, casting char * to LPCOLESTR using ATL conversion macro:

`LPCOLESTR converted_string = A2COLE(pNewCharStr);`

Comment: I made another way: pin_ptr<const WCHAR> str = PtrToStringChars(progID); LPCOLESTR coleString = (LPWSTR)str;

Comment: @MarekK Please post your answer as an answer.

Comment: [Always free the memory by calling FreeHGlobal.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This technique also looses data by converting from Unicode to ANSI to Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

I made another way:

```
// 1.
pin_ptr<const WCHAR> str = PtrToStringChars(progID);
LPCOLESTR coleString = (LPWSTR)str;
```

I have found that `pin_ptr` will be released if goes out of scope 
[Define the Scope of Pinning Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4e467k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and
 [pin_ptr (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx)
This code works well for me:

```
// 2. this is the same like (1.)
String ^progID2 = "Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1";// This is example of dynamic string
pin_ptr<const WCHAR> PINprogID2 = PtrToStringChars(progID2);
CLSID clsid2;
HRESULT result2 = CLSIDFromProgID(PINprogID2, &clsid2); //(LPCOLESTR, &CLSID)
```

Another example:

```
// 3.
pin_ptr<const WCHAR> sclsid3 = PtrToStringChars("{63D5F432-CFE4-11d1-B2C8-0060083BA1FB}");
CLSID clsid3;
CLSIDFromString((WCHAR*)sclsid3, &clsid3); //(LPOLESTR, &CLSID)
```

I am not much experienced and I am not sure if there are some lack of memory, but I think those codes are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the hammer for every nail.  C++/CLI lets you just as easily use native types.  So it is simply:

```
LPCOLESTR progid = L"Matrikon.OPC.Server";
// etc..
```

Non-zero odds (always say why) that you can simply use Type::GetTypeFromProgID().

Comment: True, but to simplified my question I pasted a key part  of code. `L"Matrikon.OPC.Server"` will not be used stigth and `progID` will be dynamic.

Comment: So your question didn't match the problem you were trying to solve and the answer you selected isn't the way you solved it.  That went well.

Comment: My question match the problem exactlly. There was a purpose to use progID variable. `String ^progID = Console::ReadLine(); CLSID clsid; HRESULT result = CLSIDFromProgID(progID, &clsid);` This match that better? Answer I sellected is right but at home I do not have ATL in express. I will check that at work on monday. I far I could check `char *pNewCharStr` is correct. I tried ATL at work and I know `A2COLE` shold conver that properly. During that time I found different way to solve it because I have found `OLESTR == WCHAR`.