# Error while filling a GUID in C++

Tags: c++, guid, msdn

I'm trying to fill a GUID structure (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa373931(v=vs.85).aspx) in C++ from a std::string.

I'm trying with the following string **as an exemple (the string will be passed in parameter in the actual function)** : `"eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a"`
but yet I still get an empty GUID.

I saw the function CLSIDFromString can be used for this purpose on the MSDN Forum : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58fbd857-edef-4e77-8355-c426523cf06f/how-to-convert-cstring-to-guid-?forum=vcmfcatl

The code :

```
int main()
{
    std::string sGuid = "eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a";
    fromStringToGuid(sGuid);
}

GUID fromStringToGuid(std::string sGuid)
{
    GUID guid;
    LPCOLESTR lpcGuid = (LPWSTR) sGuid.c_str();

    std::cout << "LpcGuid : " << lpcGuid << std::endl;
    std::cout << "String GUID : " << sGuid << std::endl;

    CLSIDFromString(lpcGuid, &guid);

    std::cout << "GUID : " << std::hex << guid.Data1 << " " << guid.Data2 << " " << guid.Data3 << " " << guid.Data4;

    return guid;
}
```

The result :

```
LpcGuid : 0428ABC0
String GUID : eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a
GUID : 0 0 0 i = 0
```

The GUID should have the decimal value of `eec5ad98` instead of `0` for example.

**EDIT :**

Tried @JeffDavies method :

```
GUID guid;
const OLECHAR aoleGuid[] = OLESTR("eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a");

std::cout << "GUID before : " << guid.Data1 << " " << guid.Data2 << " " << guid.Data3 << " " << guid.Data4 << std::endl;
CLSIDFromProgID(aoleGuid, &guid);
std::cout << "GUID after : " << guid.Data1 << " " << guid.Data2 << " " << guid.Data3 << " " << guid.Data4 << std::endl;
```

I added the print of the GUID before the function but I have the same result :

```
GUID before : 1505448 30982 184 `3À
GUID after : 0 0 0 i = 0
```

Comment: sGuid should 'wstring', if you want to cast its 'c_str()' this way.

Comment: Just another case in which a cast tells the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing" even where you don't. Have you looked at `lpcGuid` in the debugger? I bet it's some random Chinese string.

Comment: @MSalters I didn't do the conversion randomly, I saw it in this Stack Overflow comment : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23973050/5271942

Comment: You saw _another_ cast there. Note the `WCHAR`, which matches the `LPWSTR`. When you have a plain `char[]`, you can cast it to `LPSTR` (no W). But you don't need such a cast: the compiler already knows they're the same. The _real_ problem is that you need  string conversion, and no cast can do that.

Comment: @MSalters Except that the std::string.c_str() method returns a const char *, so the string conversion shouldn't be a trouble, no ? Except if that's a pointer to array kind of trouble.

Comment: That would be `LPCSTR` in Win32 speak. Still not a `LPCWSTR`, and certainly not a `LPWSTR`. (You can cast a `LPCWSTR` to `LPCOLESTR` too, both are const-qualified.)

Comment: If you look at memory can you see what aoleGuid is pointing at? could it be a byte order issue?

Comment: Ah wait, don't you want that CLSIDFromProgID to be CLSIDFromString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find anything, I did research about all of the GUID format, so I will post what I did for the next people having the same problem as I had.

The GUID structure is composed of 4 variables :

- Data1 (unsigned long)
- Data2 (unsigned long)
- Data3 (unsigned long)
- Data4[8] (unsigned long array)

So to decompose a string in the format "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", you have to put the first 00000000 in Data1, the next 0000 in Data2 and the next 0000 in Data3, all in an hexadecimal to decimal conversion.

For data4, the 2 first bytes corresponds to the next 0000 and all the others are
the numbers two by two of the 000000000000 part.

C++ code :

```
GUID            fromStringToGUID(std::string strguid)
{
    GUID guid;

    int i = 2;
    std::vector<std::string> bytes = split(strguid, "-");
    std::string last = bytes[bytes.size() - 1];

    guid.Data1 = fromStringToHex(bytes[0]);
    guid.Data2 = fromStringToHex(bytes[1]);
    guid.Data3 = fromStringToHex(bytes[2]);

    guid.Data4[0] = fromStringToHex(bytes[3].substr(0, 2));
    guid.Data4[1] = fromStringToHex(bytes[3].substr(2, 2));

    for (int j = 0; j < last.size(); j+=2)
    {
        guid.Data4[i] = fromStringToHex(last.substr(j, 2));
        i++;
    }
    return guid;
}

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str, std::string sep)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    int from;
    int i;
    int to;

    from = 0;
    to = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == sep[0])
        {
            to = i;
            result.push_back(str.substr(from, to - from));
            from = i + 1;
        }
    }
    result.push_back(str.substr(from, to - from));
    return result;
}

unsigned long fromStringToHex(std::string number)
{
    std::stringstream sts;
    unsigned long value;

    sts << number;
    sts >> std::hex >> value;

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to this page, this should be one way to do it: (the cast doesn't seem to be working so perhaps is not Unicode in the right format - I presume it's looking for UTF16 but might be UTF8)

```
// substitute in std::string for the literal
const OLECHAR wszGuid[] = OLESTR("eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a");
CLSIDFromString(wszGuid, &guid);
```

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?224120-What-s-the-type-quot-LPCOLESTR-quot

This implies that char/w_char is autoswitched, but the memory must have been allocated in a special way (hence wrapping in OLESTR), presumably c_str doesn't allocate in the special way.

[What's the meaning of BSTR, LPCOLESTR, and others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607266/whats-the-meaning-of-bstr-lpcolestr-and-others)

Comment: It didn't work, I edited my post so you can see the code and results.

Comment: @sh5164 by accident you used CLSIDFromProgID  rather than CLSIDFromString  probably because the page I linked to used that. I think that attempts to find the class in the registry or something.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542998(v=vs.85).aspx

```
//#include <initguid.h> //application call header
//#include <guiddef.h>  //macro definition
DEFINE_GUID( GUID_BUS_TYPE_PCMCIA, 0x09343630L, 0xaf9f, 0x11d0, 
    0x92,0x9f, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x4f, 0xc3, 0x40, 0xb1 );
```

Comment: Useful if I had a static GUID to declare, I'll edit my question to precise I need this method to work with as many string as I want.